# AWS: conditional route to EC2 depending on content

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-route53, amazon-vpc

I want to build a cluster of EC2 "worker" instances where each EC2 should handle particular shard of users, lets say:

- EC2-1 handles users-1-2-3
- EC2-2 handles users-4-5-6
- EC2-3 handles users-7-8-9

So that when user-3 tries to login and execute other requests in my service, each request from that user always gets directed to the same EC2-1, so that I can have all information related to specific user hosted on one machine, in heap (to reduce the load on database and avoid complex queries from different partitions, but that's different story).

what is the best way to do this in Amazon?

I guess, for that I need to maintain some kind of mapping table (userId <-> instanceIp).
One option I thought about is having additional "routing" EC2 instance (or cluster of at least 2 of them, for failover, fronted by ELB) which only manages redirects to "worker" instances (in the same region) according to such mapping table and keeps the table updated (probably, each "worker" instance should somehow report that its up and running and managing users-X-Y-Z).

But maybe there is a way to do it via Amazon services without additional "routing" EC2?
I've read some docs about VPC, Route53 and Geo routing, but the closest thing I could find was http://docs.aws.amazon.com/Route53/latest/DeveloperGuide/rrsets-working-with.html
but I'm not sure if this is the right thing, because there could be millions of users on each "worker" EC2 and I don't know it works for dynamic content such as user ids.

yeah and I hope it will be like 2 millions of users per worker EC2...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are probably looking for is sticky sessions on the ELB. This will route all traffic per session to a single host. This has some downsides, such as losing the session of the instance fails. (Unless its shared)

Taking the clustering route generally involves some overhead. Either by redirecting the user after login to their assigned cluster, or internally routing traffic via proxy to the application server assigned to the user.

Comment: if the asker wants hardcore sharding, it won't help. sticky sessions makes a best effort to use the same host for each client, but can't route to shards (e.g., servers 1-2-3 handle usernames starting with A-F). there are a few architectural problems anyhow, but it could be handled with a few clusters/ELBs and redirects, I suppose.

Comment: @datasage thanks for the tip about sticky sessions! if I don't find any other way I'll give them a try

Comment: @tedder42 yeah I wanted "hardcore" sharding, I guess. btw, you've mentioned some architectural problems, do you advise against this approach? I don't have much experience with amazon, maybe I'm giving birth to a monster? if so, it's better to kill it now than later haha

Comment: @blackdigger it's fairly opinion-based, so I don't want to give it as an answer, but machines should be stateless (as much as possible). I'm assuming you need 'session' information. That's a great use for memcached or redis.